# How to select unique records from mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
table1

id|col1|col2|col3 

table2 

id|colA|colB|colC
```

both table has is as primary key

col1 in table1 is unique and would not allow duplicate value. I am trying to migrate the data from table2 to table1. The columns are mapped in the following manner

```
table1.id => table2.id
table1.col1 => table2.colA
table1.col2 => table2.colB
table1.col3 => table2.colC
```

I Used the following query to migrate the data

```
inert into table1 select id,colA,colB,colC from table2
```

Mysql complain about colA having duplicate value. Then I use

```
insert into table1 select id,distinct(colA),colB,colC from table2
```

Mysql complain about bad syntax. Could you please help me writing the correct query to migrate data from table2 to table1.

Thanks

Comment: Is the `table1` empty at the moment?

Comment: @ypercube - yes it is empty at this moment

Comment: And what should happen if there are 2 or more rows in `table2` with same value in `colA`? Which should be inserted into `table1`?

Comment: @ypercube: I would simply discard it at this moment.

Comment: Discard both (or all) duplicates? Or choose one at random and insert it?

Comment: @ypercube what would be the difference between query if we discard everything or choose at random - currently I would choose random

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, you can lose some data, while saving in this way. Because If colB and colC are different for the same colA, only one of the rows will be saved.

You can use this query:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
    SELECT id,colA,colB,colC 
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY colA;
```

Comment: -1 This may actually result in values (in columns `id`, `colB` and `colC`) that come from **different** rows in table2.